# Getting a warning when adding the new google one tap login in internally used web app and its dynamically created subdomains

Tags: laravel, google-oauth, google-signin, google-one-tap

I am trying to add the google one tap login to our internal website but I am getting the following warning. Although I have already added the main domain and sub domain(just to test) in Authorized redirect URIs and Authorized JavaScript origins but still getting this error.

I read in the document where it says no verification is required when the app is used internally.

Thanks in advance for any guidance

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to add the new "Sign in with Google" option on the websites which are hosted on the dynamically created subdomains, one can use the solution provided by google is its [integration via iframe](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/amp/intermediate-iframe).

The annoying part is that the documentation didn't mentioned this solution as another possible solution in its [subdomain section](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/subdomains).